# Datamaps D3 done function Link

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datamaps

I want that if you click to a link in Datamaps (D3), you get to a special Link, but this should be just possible, if the variable blogentries is >0 or is set.

My Code:

```js
<script>
 var map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById('worldmap'),
  responsive: true,
  geographyConfig: {
   highlightOnHover: false,
   popupOnHover: false
  },
  fills: {
   'VISITED': '#13304F',
   defaultFill: '#d6e5f5'
  },
  data: {
   'FIN': {
    fillKey: 'VISITED',
    blogentries: 1
   },
   'AUT': {
    fillKey: 'VISITED',
    blogentries: 1
   },
  },
  done: function(datamap) {
   datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {
        if (data.blogentries > 0) {
      window.location = "https://www.link.com/" + (geography.properties.name);
        }
   });
  }
 });
 // Pure JavaScript
 window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  map.resize();
 });

 // Alternatively with d3
 d3.select(window).on('resize', function() {
  map.resize();
 });
 // Alternatively with jQuery
 $(window).on('resize', function() {
  map.resize();
 });
</script>
```

Thx for your help

Comment: do you really need 3 resize handler?

Comment: is from the docu (https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps#responsive-maps) but I don't think this is the problem, the line with the if  (data.blogentries>0) doesn't work

Comment: No, but resizing the chart 3 times is also not very efficient. You have to choose one of the 3

Comment: ok thx :) removed 2/3 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if (d3.select(geography).datum().blogentries > 0) {
    // ....
}
```

**Edit**

You have to put the map-fill-data in a separate variable and use the `geography.id` to get the value for `blogentries`

```
var mapData = {
  'FIN': {
    fillKey: 'VISITED',
    blogentries: 1
  },
  'AUT': {
    fillKey: 'VISITED',
    blogentries: 1
  },
};
var map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById('worldmap'),
  responsive: true,
  geographyConfig: {
    highlightOnHover: false,
    popupOnHover: false
  },
  fills: {
    'VISITED': '#13304F',
    defaultFill: '#d6e5f5'
  },
  data: mapData,
  done: function(datamap) {
    datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {
      if (mapData[geography.id] && mapData[geography.id].blogentries > 0) {
        window.location = "https://www.test.com/" + (geography.properties.name);
      }
    });
  }
});
```